# Inserting a value based on another values result into MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need a bit of help on a sticky situation.

Currently I have an array that looks like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Task_ID] => 59
        [email] => m@m.com
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Task_ID] => 59
        [email] => m@m.com
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Task_ID] => 59
        [email] => z@z.com
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Task_ID] => 60
        [email] => m@m.com
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Task_ID] => 60
        [email] => z@z.com
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [Task_ID] => 61
        [email] => z@z.com
    )

)
```

Here is my current insert statement.

```
        if(is_array($myArr)){
        $valuesArr = array();
        foreach($myArr as $row){

            $sql = "INSERT INTO user_data (Task_ID, email, url) values ";
            $TaskID = (int) $row['Task_ID'];
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['email'] );

            $valuesArr[] = "('$TaskID', '$email')";
            $sql .= "('$TaskID', '$email')";
            mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error());
        }
    }
```

What I would like to do is insert a new value that is NOT in the array which is the URL value.

For the URL I would like to increment a number with each unique email, where the same email will get the same URL value.

An example of what the SQL syntax SHOULD look like.

```
INSERT INTO user_data (TaskID, email, url) values ('60', 'm@m.com','1')
INSERT INTO user_data (TaskID, email, url) values ('80', 'm@m.com','1')
INSERT INTO user_data (TaskID, email, url) values ('82', 'z@z.com','2')
INSERT INTO user_data (TaskID, email, url) values ('62', 'z@z.com','2')
INSERT INTO user_data (TaskID, email, url) values ('42', 'z@z.com','2')
INSERT INTO user_data (TaskID, email, url) values ('61', 'a@a.com','3')
INSERT INTO user_data (TaskID, email, url) values ('81', 'a@a.com','3')
INSERT INTO user_data (TaskID, email, url) values ('92', 't@t.com','4')
INSERT INTO user_data (TaskID, email, url) values ('32', 't@t.com','4')
INSERT INTO user_data (TaskID, email, url) values ('72', 't@t.com','4')
```

Notice the URL increasing by one for each email change. Please note that TaskID is NOT the PK and the emails are not in order.

Thank you for reading very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try

```
if (is_array($myArr)) {
    $valuesArr = array();
    $addedEmails = array();

    $cnt = 0;
    foreach($myArr as $row){

        $sql = "INSERT INTO user_data (Task_ID, email, url) values ";
        $TaskID = (int) $row['Task_ID'];
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['email'] );

        if (!in_array($email, $addedEmails)) {
            $cnt++;
            $addedEmails[] = $email;
        }

        $valuesArr[] = "('$TaskID', '$email', '$cnt')";
        $sql .= "('$TaskID', '$email', '$cnt')";
        mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error());
    }
}
```